# Confused about Spring-Data DDD repository pattern

Tags: spring, domain-driven-design, nosql, repository-pattern, spring-data

I don't know so much about DDD repository pattern but the implementation in Spring is confusion me.

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> { … }
```

As the interface extends JpaRepository (or MongoDBRepository...), if you change from one db to another, you have to change the interface as well.

For me an interface is there to provide some abstraction, but here it's not so much abstract...

Do you know why Spring-Data works like that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are right, an Interface is an abstraction about something that works equals for all implementing classes, from an outside point of view.

And that is exactly what happens here:

- JpaRepository is a common view of all your JPA Repositories (for all the different Entities), while MongoDBRepository is the same for all MongoDB Entities.
- But JpaRepository and MongoDBRepository have nothing in common, except the stuff that is defined in there common super Interfaces:

  - org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository
  - org.springframework.data.repository.Repository

So for me it looks normal.

If you use the classes that implement your Repository then use PagingAndSortingRepository or Repository if you want to be able to switch from an JPA implementation to an Document based implementation (*sorry but I can not imagine such a use case - anyway*). And of course your Repository implementation should implement the correct interface (JpaRepository, MongoDBRepository) depending on what it is.

Comment: Actually if you know in the interface that a Repository implementation is of the given type, why use an interface at all? But i guess like you it's hard to do better...

Comment: I would think/expect that a change from a RDBMS to a Document-oriented store would require significant changes on the object/domain model. No matter what, *persistence abstractions leak up* in one way or another.  Always. If one could simply  change from JpaRepository to MongoDBRepository without major alterations to the domain model, I would surmise that the domain model was not that complex to begin with. Nothing wrong with that as some applications are like that.

Answer (score 8):

The reasoning behind this is pretty clearly stated in this blog post http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/10/getting-started-with-spring-data-jpa/.

> Defining this interface serves two purposes: First, by extending JpaRepository we get a bunch of generic CRUD methods into our type that allows saving Accounts, deleting them and so on. Second, this will allow the Spring Data JPA repository infrastructure to scan the classpath for this interface and create a Spring bean for it.

If you do not trust sources so close to the source (pun intended) it might be a good idea to read this post as well http://www.brucephillips.name/blog/index.cfm/2011/3/25/Using-Spring-Data-JPA-To-Reduced-Data-Access-Coding.

> What I did not need to code is an implementation of the PersonRepository interface. Spring will create an implementation of this interface and make a PersonRepository bean available to be autowired into my Service class. The PersonRepository bean will have all the standard CRUD methods (which will be transactional) and return Person objects or collection of Person objects. So by using Spring Data JPA, I've saved writing my own implementation class.

Comment: i don't care about implementation. And if the repository just have to be scanned, why not extending a more common repository interface? They talk about saving and deleting, i don't know su much about mongoDB but i guess we can do these operations too on mongoDB... If you expose methods like flush to your services, you make them orm dependent right?

Answer (score 3):

Until M2 of Spring Data we required users to extend `JpaRepository` due to the following reasons:

1. The classpath scanning infrastructure only picked up interfaces extending that interface as one might use Spring Data JPA and Spring Data Mongo in parallel and have both of them pointed to the very same package it would not be clear which store to create the proxy for. However since RC1 we simply leave that burden to the developer as we think it's a rather exotic case and the benefit of just using `Repository`, `CrudRepository` or the like outweights the effort you have to take in the just described corner case. You can use `exclude` and `include` elements in the namespace to gain finer-grained control over this.
2. Until M2 we had transactionality applied to the CRUD methods by redeclaring the CRUD methods and annotating them with `@Transactional`. This decision in turn was driven by the algorithm `AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource` uses to find transaction configuration. As we wanted to provide the user with the possibility to reconfigure transactions by just redeclaring a CRUD method in the concrete repository interface and applying `@Transactional` on it. For RC1 we decided to implement a custom `TransactionAttributeSource` to be able to move the annotations back to the repository CRUD implementation.

Long story short, here's what it boils down to:

As of RC1 there's no need to extend the store specific repository interface anymore, **except** you want to…

1. Use `List`-based access to `findAll(…)` instead of the `Iterable`-based one in the more core repository interfaces (allthough you could simply redeclare the relevant methods in a common base interface to return `List`s as well)
2. You want to make use of the JPA-specific methods like `saveAndFlush(…)` and so on.

Generally you are much more flexible regarding the exposure of CRUD methods since RC1 as you can even only extend the `Repository` marker interface and selectively add the CRUD methods you want to expose. As the backing implementation will still implement all of the methods of `PagingAndSortingRepository` we can still route the calls to the instance:

```
public interface MyBaseRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends Repository<T, ID> {

  List<T> findAll();

  T findOne(ID id);
}

public interface UserRepository extends MyBaseRepository<User, Long> {

  List<T> findByUsername(String username);
}
```

In that example we define `MyBaseRepository` to only expose `findAll()` and `findOne(…)` (which will be routed into the instance implementing the CRUD methods) and the concrete repository adding a finder method to the two CRUD ones.

For more details on that topic please consult the [reference documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/1.0.0.RC1/reference/html/#d0e198).